# Core Data is saving only the last item

Tags: ios, core-data, save, overriding

I'm still new at Core Data.

I'm trying to loop three times over an array and at each loop, I'm saving the index number.

But it's only showing the last index number when fetching the results. It's overriding everything that was inserted before.

My code is written in the AppDelegate.

Here's my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *tagsDB = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tags" inManagedObjectContext:context];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
   [tagsDB setValue:i forKey:@"ID"];

}

[self saveContext];
```

...

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I re-declare the NSManagedObject at each iteration, all the data is saved but I always get an extra row of null values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create your entity for each value.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
   NSManagedObject *tagsDB = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tags" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   [tagsDB setValue:i forKey:@"ID"];

}

[self saveContext];
```

Comment: When I re-declare the NSManagedObject at each iteration, all the data is saved but I always get an extra row of null values

Comment: Extra row appears when you execute a query on your DB?

Comment: so it's normal to have this extra row? Can i get rid of it?

Comment: Extra rows appears when you perform a request on your DB, they are called fault, to avoid it use [YOURFETCHREQUEST setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

Comment: Thank you Tom for your replies. This is my code for the fetched. It's still returning one null row. 

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tags"];
    
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

....

Comment: My Mistake. I was adding an extra declaration of NSManagedObject before the for loop. Thanks a lot Tom!

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop - the code that gets reiterated simply changes the value of the new inserted item. What you need to be doing in the for loop is `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` which will insert a new, separate entity for each iteration.